# How do I bulk update organization subtypes using a profile?

Tags: profile

I've been trying to use the 'Update Multiple Contacts' feature from within a Group using a profile. The profile field is 'Organization Subtype'

However, when I get the list of contacts to update, and click in the field, no results with the error 'none found' shows up, even though on my database there are a few different subtypes. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem sounded vaguely familiar, and I just found out why.

This is logged on the (old) CiviCRM issue tracker as [CRM-17451](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17451).  The answer was that someone would have to write this functionality or [work with the core team](https://civicrm.org/work-with-the-core-team) to do so.  However, I also see that I found a workaround back in 2016.  From the page:

> In non-technical terms: Profiles secretly have a contact type they're
>   associated with. You can see this if you try to add an
>   organization-specific field to a profile, then an individual-specific
>   field. You'll get the error "Cannot add or update profile field type
>   Individual with combination of Household or Organization". That's
>   because Civi has decided this is a profile associated with
>   Organizations. However, when you don't have any contact type-specific
>   fields on a profile, your profile defaults to a contact type of
>   "Individual" for many purposes. So individual contact subtypes are
>   loaded.
>
> The workaround: Add an organization-specific field (like "Organization
>   Name") to your profile, and this problem goes away.